# Is it possible to patch "istio-sidecar-injector" ConfigMap using oc patch command?

Tags: istio

As upstream istio automatic sidecar injection configuration also deploy the sidecar container to builder and deployer pod (for openshift .. when you use S2I) we have to patch the ConfigMap (istio-sidecar-injector) and have the exception to not to have the sidercar container inject to builder and deployer pod.

for example we have to manually add the below exception in the ConfigMap.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: istio-sidecar-injector
data:
  config: |-
    policy: enabled
    neverInjectSelector:
      - matchExpressions:
        - {key: openshift.io/build.name, operator: Exists}
      - matchExpressions:
        - {key: openshift.io/deployer-pod-for.name, operator: Exists}
    template: |-
      initContainers:
```

Question: I am trying to automate this using shell script and facing challenge while updating below parameter pro-grammatically.

```
neverInjectSelector:
      - matchExpressions:
        - {key: openshift.io/build.name, operator: Exists}
      - matchExpressions:
        - {key: openshift.io/deployer-pod-for.name, operator: Exists}
```

Is it possible to use oc patch command to update below configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: istio-sidecar-injector
data:
  config: |-
    policy: enabled
neverInjectSelector:
[ ]
```

to

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: istio-sidecar-injector
data:
  config: |-
    policy: enabled
    neverInjectSelector:
      - matchExpressions:
        - {key: openshift.io/build.name, operator: Exists}
      - matchExpressions:
        - {key: openshift.io/deployer-pod-for.name, operator: Exists}
    template: |-
      initContainers:
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an oc patch command ... I think we can achieve the same by following below code which may not be elegant solution.

```
oc project istio-system #change to the project

oc export cm istio-sidecar-injector >> exception.yaml #export the existing cm

sed -i '8s/.*/      - matchExpressions:\n        - {key: openshift.io\/build.name, operator: Exists}\n      - matchExpressions:\n        - {key: openshift.io\/deployer-pod-for.name, operator: Exists}/' exception.yaml
kubectl apply -f exception.yaml
```